# What is the correct tense to use for a sentence like this?

Tags: grammar, tenses

This sentence is wrong:

> This website was first on the list of
>   priorities and your feedback over the
>   past two years is much appreciated.

I do not know why.  It reads funny.  I'm not an English expert.

Comment: It's two separate clauses, each in a different tense.  While it doesn't make much sense without any context, the only grammatical error in the sentence is that there should be a comma before the *and*.

Comment: @snumpy: Agreed. And given the current trend to prune non-essential commas, I wouldn't even say that's a significant error anyway. But semantically it seems like a bit of a non-sequitor to juxtapose 'first priority' and 'two years'. I noticed that more than the missing comma, to be honest.

Comment: Considering a 'narrative' angle, there are other sources of awkwardness. As said above, there are two clauses with two different tenses, yes, but part of the awkwardness arises through shifting 'focalisation'. First the focus is on the website, then, via feedback, focus is forced onto feedback. The readers 'pause' is part tense, part focalisation - for the latter, one can't help think "Ah! the 'priorities list' is about communication, the feedback is too: that's the focus". The 2nd clause is also quite passive; "your feedback" (on the website?) much appreciated (by a company? one person?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the bit that bothers you is

**...is much appreciated**.

There's nothing inherently wrong with that construction, grammatically or sematically. But I think many people might say it would read more 'naturally' if you changed it to

**...has been much appreciated**.

That will get rid of the slight unease created by the sentence switching from past to present tense.

Comment: Thanks.  I think it's okay to go in a literary work, but not for the web.  http://www.useit.com/alertbox/designmistakes.html Writing for the Web means making content •short, •scannable, and •to the point (rather than full of fluffy marketese).

Comment: Ok, well if your command of English is such that you're qualified to classify **has been** as 'fluffy marketese' suitable for a 'literary work', I guess you didn't need my advice in the first place.

Comment: I missed my explanantion, entirely.  that is one sentence from a half page worth of writing.  To simply say, "subscribe now".